# How to mark myself unavailable on specific weekday(s) every week?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using Microsoft Outlook v. 16.38 on a Mac.

I want my Outlook calendar to show me as unavailable for meetings<sup>1</sup> every Thursday and Friday of every week.

The only way I have found to implement this availability pattern would require me to create six 3-hour "appointments", each recurring weekly, and timed so that they cover the two weekdays.

Is there a better way?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Actually, I don't object to having occasional, one-time appointments during those days.  It is only *recurring* meetings that I really want to avoid during those days.  I realize, however, that this is a much finer distinction than I can hope Outlook to provide any support for.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me that this would do it with two appointments for Thursday and Friday:

- Home > New Appointment
- In the *Show As* drop down list select "Out of Office"
- Select "None" from the *Reminder* drop down list
- Click the *Recurrence* button and in the Appointment Recurrence dialog box specify:

  - In the *Appointment time* section specify "All day event"
  - In the Recurrence pattern section check *Weekly*
  - In the *Range of recurrence* section specify as needed
  - Click the OK button.
- Back in the appointment window, after making any other required changes,
  click *Save & Close*.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

### How to mark yourself as "away" (out of office) in the Microsoft Outlook web app / PWA desktop-like app

On Linux Ubuntu 22.04 (note: [use the X11 window manager, not Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/a/1470563/327339)), I have installed the Microsoft Outlook PWA web app via the Edge Browser. It works great, and allows adding a shortcut to the program in the side bar/Ubuntu launcher:

[image]

To mark myself unavailable, I just need to set up a recurring "Away" meeting, like this:

Open the "Outlook (PWA)" program --> click "New event" in the top left --> choose "Away" from the dropdown menu at the top (it said "Busy" for me by default). Then, add an event name, optionally set it to "Private", choose a time, or check "All day", choose a recurring time period ("Weekly" in my case), etc., as shown here:

[image]

and:

[image]